# Python-Append results of multiple inputs and print them all together as single output

Tags: python

```
n=int(input("Enter no. of divisions:"))
for i in range(n):
    (x, y) = map(int,input().split())
    m=x/y
    print(m)
```

This is a sample code which takes 2 inputs at a time  and gives the result after entering each input.

The output i'm getting is:

```
Enter no. of divisions:3
6 3
2.0
8 4
2.0
15 3
5.0
```

But i need the output as

```
Enter no. of divisions:3
6 3
8 4
15 3
2.0
2.0
5.0
```

I need all the results to print together.How do i append the results?plz help

Comment: Can you specify the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two loops, saving the results on the first:

```
n = int(input("Enter no. of divisions:"))
results = []
for i in range(n):
    (x,y) = map(int,input().split())
    results.append(x/y)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```